# Skype login from C# form

Tags: c#, authentication, skype

I didn't find out how to login from a form in C# to Skype. Is there a possibility to do that? e.g. I type my username and password in a form and when I click sign in, an instance of skype will launch and log me with my credentials.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can launch skype with command-line arguments like this:

```
 skype.exe /username:your.username /password:your.password
```

Found reference [here](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=4559&view=findpost&p=3251655&s=5c58a3e26823e243de2c4097d037e22d), and tested working on my machine (Skype 5.1). It seems this is not officially documented, so it may disappear in future versions of Skype.

Use [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) to launch a program from C#.

Comment: what about loging in? as i've seen the skype.exe /username.. command just pops up a skype login in.

Comment: @elisa that's odd - it actually logs in for me. Did you have it exactly as `/username:yourname /password:yourpassword`, with the `:`s intact?

Comment: from cmd.exe i navigate to skype\phone and then i put the command[>skype.exe /username:xxx /password:xxxx] and i then pressed enter. it just pops up my login windows. it doesn't actually signing in me to skype. any ideea why?

Answer (score 0):

May be you could make use of the Skype4COM, an activex component available from Skype. You can download it from : http://developer.skype.com/accessories

Answer (score -1):

This works only when the checkbox "sign me on when skype starts" is checked in the login window. Unless it doesn't.