# How we can call third party windows app like skype and fill username and password using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s a good, if any, .NET Windows automation library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052915/whats-a-good-if-any-net-windows-automation-library)

I am trying to call third party app using C#

```
var Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\Skype.exe";
```

However I want to fill username and password using c# code and to hit login using code.

Any idea?

Comment: Just google it. "Skype API c#"
Examples [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259923/implementation-of-skype-api), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330778/Skypekit-NET), [3](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SEHE), etc.

Comment: Refer to this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419234/skype-login-from-c-sharp-form

Comment: don't actually want to call skype using c#, skype is just used as example. but it is needed for another windows app

Comment: It may surprise you to learn - there's no *standard* way that login credentials are passed between applications. If you've got a *specific* application, you need to give details of that application.

Comment: I understand there is no standard way. But i have an application built by another developer and it can be used to login to any windows app using that. I am just looking for how we can achieve that using c#

Comment: I can't reconcile the comment "I understand there is no standard way" with your other queries, where you're asking for us to give information in a generic, non-specific manner.

Comment: If you think its no standard way for you. then its fine. But in programming anything can be achieved. Let me know if you don't agree.

Comment: Also that is just a small application which is built by a programmer in our area.